# EF Code First, no edmmetadata table

Tags: ef-code-first

I am reading through the book EF Code First by Julie Lerman. In the book, a database is created which contains tables generated from the domain model, as well a table named edmmetadatatable. Apparently, this table is needed for checking if there are any changes made to the other tables.

But, I don't have it. And I don't know how to get it.

One thing I did differently from the book was that I added my own connection string since code first defaults for SQLEXPRESS and I don't have SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is covering Entity Framework 4.2 which uses the `EdmMetadata` table. When migrations were introduced in EF 4.3, a `__MigrationHistory` table was introduced instead.

See [here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/) for more information.